# Checking Validity of Path in Makefile

Tags: makefile

I have a system where all the machines have something like a `/workarea/myjob` directory.  However, some jobs are distributed, so users need to cd to their run directory using `/net/<hostname>/workarea/myjob`

If the user tries to build without having `/net/<hostname>` in the path then job will eventually fail.

I'd like to check that `pwd` returns a path of the form `/net/<hostname>/workarea` in the Makefile before I start the build.

What is a good way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GNU make current directory is in `${CURDIR}` variable. The test can look something like:

```
hostname := $(shell hostname)
ifeq ($(findstring /net/${hostname}/workarea, ${CURDIR}),)
$(error "Wrong current directory: ${CURDIR}")
endif
```